# Autofac - How to get class name while creating instance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I have question about Autofac :
How can I get name of class which request instance from container?

Is it possible to get name of the class "Autofac_Test" passed into constructor by autofac when object is created?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using Autofac;
using Xunit;

public class BootStrap
{
    public IContainer Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register(b => new MyLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType)).As<ILog>();
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
public class Autofac_Test
{
    private IContainer _containter;
    public Autofac_Test()
    {
        _containter = new BootStrap().Configure();
    }
    [Fact]
    public void Should_create_class_with_Name_BlaBla()
    {
        var logger = _containter.Resolve<ILog>();
        Assert.True(logger.Name == "Autofac_Test");
    }
}
public class MyLogger : ILog
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public MyLogger(Type name)
    {
        Name = name.FullName;
    }
    public void Info(string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, message));
    }
}

public interface ILog
{
    void Info(string message);
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Comment: Is it correct that you can't/don't want to consider resolving some ILogFactory instead or provide this type as a parameter manually (since you're using service locator here)?

Comment: Maybe, I should consider like You said... thanks for help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your specific case it will be quite difficult to obtain this information. But as I understand the question, `MyLogger` need to know the type name where it will be injected and the code sample may not be relevant.

In this case you can use a module and the Preparing event :

```
public class LoggingModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Type limitType = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
            e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[] {
                new ResolvedParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger), 
                                      (pi, c) => c.Resolve<ILogger>(new NamedParameter("name", limitType.Name))),
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Then you will have to register your module like this :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule<LoggingModule>();
builder.RegisterType<MyLogger>().As<ILogger>();
```

Now each time a `ILogger` will be injected to a type it will have the correct name.

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(ILogger logger)
    {
        this._loggerName = logger.Name;
    }

    private readonly String _loggerName; 

    public String LoggerName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this._loggerName;
        }
    }
}
```

`LoggerName` will be `Foo`.

Your test can now look like this :

```
[Fact]
public void Should_create_class_with_Name_BlaBla()
{
    var foo = _containter.Resolve<Foo>();
    Assert.AreEquals("foo", foo.LoggerName, "invalid loggerName");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your help, but your code doesn't work. Maybe I'm so tired.

Comment: in method : void AttachToComponentRegistration(.... I got exception :

Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor (System.Type)' on type 'MyLogger'. ---> Unable cast object of type 'System.String' type 'System.Type'. (See inner exception for details.)

Comment: This is cause by `new NamedParameter("name", limitType.Name)))`. Your `MyLogger` expect a paramer `name` of type `Type`. My code sans the name of the type not the type itself. Change your constructor to accept a String or change the line to `new NamedParameter("name", limitType)))`

Comment: Ok, but still is problem because it return class name "Foo" while I need name of class which request object (in this case : "Autofac_Test")

Comment: I think your test is wrong and you are not testing what your application use. A logger usually need to know the class where it is injected, this is what the code do. With your test, you don't inject `ILogger` you only resolve it. Your application should not resolve it but use injection. I modified the test to inject ILogger in Foo and to check that `ILogger` injected in `Foo` knows where it have been injected.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

@Cyril Durand has proved it possible. Suggestion below is still correct but not that good.

<del>It doesn't look like autofac supports what you want. You can of cause parse call stack in MyLogger constructor but this will cost you performance.</del>

There's already a question about very similar thing and factory was suggested instead

[Autofac. Register class with constructor with params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337212/autofac-register-class-with-constructor-with-params)